# Why am I getting "unknown error" with authenticateviaoauth() on google earth engine?

Tags: javascript, html, google-oauth, google-earth-engine

I'm trying this html file that google provides as an example however I got "unknown error"when I run it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/earthengine/0.1.363/earthengine-api.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map. */
      #map-container {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #eee;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The "Sign in with Google" button, initially hidden. -->
    <input
      id="g-sign-in"
      type="image"
      src="https://developers.google.com/identity/images/btn_google_signin_light_normal_web.png"
      onclick="onSignInButtonClick()"
      alt="Sign in with Google"
      hidden
    />

    <!-- Element where map will be added. -->
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script>
      // The OAuth Client ID from the Google Developers Console.
      const CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
      
      // Initializes Maps JavaScript API and Earth Engine API, instructing the map
      // to pull tiles from Earth Engine and to overlay them on the map.
      function setUpMap() {
        // Hide the sign-in button.
        document.getElementById("g-sign-in").setAttribute("hidden", "true");
      
        // Initialize the Earth Engine API. Must be called once before using the API.
        ee.initialize();
      
        // Get a reference to the placeholder DOM element to contain the map.
        const mapContainerEl = document.getElementById("map-container");
      
        // Create an interactive map inside the placeholder DOM element.
        const embeddedMap = new google.maps.Map(mapContainerEl, {
          // Pan and zoom initial map viewport to Grand Canyon.
          center: {lng: -112.8598, lat: 36.2841},
          zoom: 9,
        });
      
        // Obtain reference to digital elevation model and apply algorithm to
        // calculate slope.
        const srtm = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4");
        const slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm);
      
        // Create a new tile source to fetch visible tiles on demand and display them
        // on the map.
        const mapId = slope.getMap({min: 0, max: 60});
        const tileSource = new ee.layers.EarthEngineTileSource(mapId);
        const overlay = new ee.layers.ImageOverlay(tileSource);
        embeddedMap.overlayMapTypes.push(overlay);
      }
      
      // Handles clicks on the sign-in button.
      function onSignInButtonClick() {
        // Display popup allowing the user to sign in with their Google account and to
        // grant appropriate permissions to the app.
        ee.data.authenticateViaPopup(setUpMap);
      }
      
      // If the user is signed in, display a popup requesting permissions needed to
      // run the app, otherwise show the sign-in button.
      ee.data.authenticateViaOauth(
        // The OAuth Client ID defined above.
        CLIENT_ID,
        // Callback invoked immediately when user is already signed in.
        setUpMap,
        // Show authentication errors in a popup.
        alert,
        // Request permission to only read and compute Earth Engine data on behalf of
        // user.
        /* extraScopes = */ ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/earthengine.readonly'],
        // Show sign-in button if reusing existing credentials fails.
        () => document.getElementById("g-sign-in").removeAttribute("hidden"),
        // Don't require ability to write and access Cloud Platform on behalf of the
        // user.
        /* opt_suppressDefaultScopes = */ true
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried creating a new client id with no success. The error occurs inside the authenticateViaOauth() function as the alert is inside of it. In the page were the html is in, you can replace authomatically the client id and the api key. I can replace the api key with success but I can't replace the client id. It says I got none valid but I checked and they were all created with success.

Comment: Actually No! It just won’t work. I did a work around and authenticated with the regular google api including the scope of google earth. Then I User the setAurhToken function before initializing the earth engine.